# Is there any other ways to make the program print hostname to stdout or just shellcode?

Tags: c, security, ubuntu, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

It is a lab assignment asking us to exploit this program. The first task is to call the notcalled function(which is solved by change the return address to the notcalled function :perl -e 'printf "A"x112 . "\xaddress of notcalled"') but the second task is to **construct an input string to the program that makes the program process print its current hostname to STDOUT** which I have been working on weeks. I only have one clue that is to write a shellcode into buffer and change the return address to address of buffer to active the shellcode. But may because of my wrong operation it doesn't work. (I tried used to GDB to find the address of buffer and using an exploit program to print an shellcode which could open /bin/sh to get root access to string buffer as a test. and I tried use root to **gcc-5 -o oflow oflow.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack** **chmod u+s oflow**,and etc. and I have done the syracuse University's
Buffer-Overflow Vulnerability Lab and it sucuss on my Ubuntu16-i386 server version.
http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Vulnerability/Buffer_Overflow/
 and the exploit program is learned from it)

So the question is: **To make the program print hostname to stdout**, is the idea of using shellcode correct? or is there another tricker way to print the hostname? I need only hints or tips. Thanks a lot.

```
//oflow.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    char * stuff = 0;
    int len = 0;

    vulnerable();
    return 0;
}

int
vulnerable( void ) {
    char buf[100];

    printf("Please enter your hacker name: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(buf);
    printf("\"%s\"\n can hack this?" , buf );
}

void
notcalled( void ) {
 char *secret = "Iouf jmmb, cbsb sftufo lwbs!";
 int i;

    printf("The Secret string is: ");
    for( i = 0 ; secret[i] ; i++ )
        if( secret[i] >= 'a' && secret[i] <= 'z' )
            printf("%c" , secret[i] -1 );
        else
            printf("%c" , secret[i] );
    printf("\n");
}
```

my exploit code is here[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmoAg.jpg
 because it is on vitural box. so I put a screenshot here.
and I followed the guide to find the return address of buffer 
the Aleph One, Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf

Comment: NEVER use `gets()`  it was depreciated several iterations back in the C standard and completely removed in the current C standard.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  Suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: This whole question is in the context of learning to exploit the `gets` vulnerability. If you replace `gets` by anything more secure, you cannot learn.

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: I suspect that one way to implement what OP wants involves using the address of the unused `argv` parameter, to get to the `envp` parameter. The environment holds the host name. Not sure it can be implemented though. If you want to implement this, you cannot remove `argc`.

Comment: regarding: `char * stuff = 0;`   the 'implicit conversion' feature of C might save you, but the statement should be written as: `char * stuff = NULL;`

Comment: @anatolyg,  the best way to get the hostname is to use: `char *hostname = getenv( "hostname" );`  where `getenv()` is exposed in the header file `stdlib.h`  followed by: `puts( hostname );`

Comment: Since OP is only looking for "hints or tips", this might be the correct answer!

Comment: @anatolyg thanks for your reply.It helps and I will think about it.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to get the host name from the environment is:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // puts()
#include <stdlib.h>   // getenv()
...
char *hostname = getenv( "HOSTNAME" ); 
if( !hostname )
    puts( "no host name available" );
else
    puts( hostname );
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips!